# change background position using query

Tags: jquery

on my site project I want the user to be able to change the banner image they have for their profiles. So far I am able to have them upload an image and it automatically be applied as a background to the header, I also have 3 radio inputs that lets them repeat-x, repeat-y, and no-repeat the banner.

My next step is to figure out how to let them choose the position of their image.

I don't want to throw 10 radio buttons giving them predefined choices as it looks ugly. I tried to take a checkbox approach and have them seletct "Top" then a second postions say "LEFT" so that would apply as `.css({'backgroundPosition' : 'top left'});`

the problem with this is that I have more than two checkboxes so it would mess up the logic of jquery.

Can someone give me some ideas as to how I can tackle this problem?

In the end I was planing on giving up and and giving them a sample rectangle with "hot spots" and just have them select the place they want the image to go along side two inputs for a numerical value for Top Left positioning (i.e. 10px 200px)

is there an elegant eye candy way to approach this?

my current code to handle the radio button click

```
$("form#frm_look_and_feel input[name='position']").each(function(){
        $(this).bind('change', function(){
            var position = $(this).val();
            $('#topHeader').css({'backgroundPosition' : position});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them 2 more radio button sets:

- One For `top` or `bottom`
- One for `left` or `right`

  ```
  <form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="topOrBottom" value="top" />Top
    <input type="radio" name="topOrBottom" value="bottom" />Bottom


    <input type="radio" name="leftOrRight" value="left" />Left
    <input type="radio" name="leftOrRight" value="right" />Right
  </form>
  ```

Then your jQuery would look as follows:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var tb = $('input[name="topOrBottom"]:checked').val(),
        lr = $('input[name="leftOrRight"]:checked').val();
    $('.whatever').css({'backgroundPosition' : tb + ' ' + lr});
});
```

Comment: hmmm, like set one = Top or Bottom and set two = Left or Right so then a combination of of set one and two would be Top Left.... hmmm interesting, how would the jquery code work in combining these two into one variable i can use like `.css({'backgroundPosition' : position});` ?

Comment: modified answer to show how you could do what you want using jQuery

Comment: i edited my original post to show what code i'm currently using

Comment: @s2xi You could prepend the names with `position`, i.e., `positionTopOrBottom` etc. and the use `$("form#frm_look_and_feel input[name^='position']")` to bind the `.change()` listener.

Comment: i was wondering if i could use an array and just have `.css({'backgroundPosition' : position[1] + ' ' + position[0]});` the problem is the spaces i suppose if i prepend the names no?

Comment: you can use position.join(' '), which puts all the values of the array into a single string separated by spaces.